# Squid upgrade stops authentication

Tags: authentication, squid

Recently we installed a squid proxy server for a customer who was using an older server. New server is ubuntu 14.04.2 with squid 3.3.8. We used the same password file to authenticate users. The problem is there are passwords longer than 8 characters and squid now is rejecting those passwords instead of truncating and checking the first 8 chars only (which is good in a sense). The customer is reluctant to change passwords of some users. Is there a way to allow passwords longer than 8 in the same way as earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there is a security issue with allowing DES encrypted passwords longer than 8 chars to authenticate squid as it truncates the password. However since no outsiders can connect to the said proxy server I have figured out that by using the basic_ncsa_auth or ncsa_auth from a squid version with new squid we can allow users to use the old 8+ char long passwords.